# How to open TFS Power Tools - Alerts Explorer

Tags: tfs, alerts, tfs-power-tools

I have TFS 2010 and Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and the April TFS 2010 Power Tools installed.  I am a Project Collection Administrator on my TFS Server (so permissions should not be an issue).

I want to open the alerts explorer, but when I right click on a project tab it is not there:

[image: Missing Alerts Explorer]

Just in case I tried upgrading to the March version of the TFS 2010 Power Tools.  There was no change.

Opening the "Project Alerts" just gets me the normal Alerts dialog.  I need to make a new alert.

Any ideas how I can get the missing menu item back?

Edit: I tried manually adding the menu item to the context menu.  But I cannot find Alerts Explorer in any of the command lists.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems Alerts Explorer is no longer available in Team Project menu.

To create an Alert, you can open Alerts Explorer in following ways:

1. From the Team menu in Visual Studio, click Alerts Explorer. 
   [image: Team > Alerts Explorer menu]
2. From the Team Explorer window, right-click the server\team project collection and then click Alerts Explorer.
   [image: Team Explorer > Alerts Explorer menu]
3. For Work Items, you can Right Click a Work Item and choose 'Alert on change..'.

[image: Right-click work item > Alert on change.. menu]

4. For Source Control, Right Click Source Control Items and choose 'Alert on Change..'.
   [image: Right-click source control > Alert on change.. menu]

Answer (score 2):

We had to install the Team Foundation Server Power Tools from December 2011 at  http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f