# How can I manage all the alerts in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-alerts

Yesterday I created few alerts for changes in specific folders in TFS (in VS 2010, Source Control Explorer: `File->Source Control...->Alert on change`). Now I see that I'm getting much more traffic than I expected so I wanted to remove some of the alerts. However I didn't find how to do that... I also didn't find how to see all the alerts I created.
I searched the web for an answer, but didn't find anything that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you right-click the server/collection name in Team Explorer, you can choose 'Alerts Explorer'. From within Alerts Explorer you can add/edit/delete alerts that you have previously created.

See this answer for screenshots: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358419/11210